# macOS statusBarApp without Storyboard create and close settingsWindow causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: macos, exc-bad-access, nswindow, programmatically-created, nsstatusbar

I have a MacOS cocoa statusBarApp without any Storyboard with main.swift file.
The statusBarIcon shows up a Menu which presents a custom view with a button, which should open a settingsWindow - which it does. If I close the settingsWindow and reopen it and close it again, I got a EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error. It seems, that the window is deallocate but the reference is still present. I don't know how to fix this.

Edit the question like Willeke´s advice:

Thx, to your answer. Ok, hier is a minimal reproducible example:

create a new Xcode project, with storyboard and swift for macOS app.
Under Project-Infos / General / Deployment Info: Delete the main entry to the storyboard. Then delete the storyboard file itself.
Under Info set the "application is agent" flag to yes, so the app is statusBarApp only.
then you only need the code below.

The Exception Breakpoint leads to this line:

```
settingsWindow = NSWindow(
```

To reproduce the error: start the app, click on statusItem, click on menuItem, a window opens, close the window, click again all first steps and reopen the window. sometimes that's the point of crash. sometimes a few more attempts of closing the window are necessary, but not more then three times.

main.swift

```
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate
_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    var settingsWindow: NSWindow!
    
    var statusItemMain: NSStatusItem?
    var menuMain = NSMenu()
    var menuItemMain = NSMenuItem()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
                
        statusItemMain = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        let itemImage = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "power", accessibilityDescription: nil)
        itemImage?.isTemplate = true
        statusItemMain?.button?.image = itemImage
        
        menuItemMain.target = self
        menuItemMain.isEnabled = true
        menuItemMain.action = #selector(createWindow)
        menuMain.addItem(menuItemMain)
        
        menuMain.addItem(.separator())
                
        statusItemMain?.menu = menuMain
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    @objc func createWindow() {
        settingsWindow = NSWindow(
                    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 750, height: 500),
                    styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled],
                    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        settingsWindow.center()
        settingsWindow.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        settingsWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        settingsWindow?.contentViewController = ViewController()
    }


}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func loadView() {
    self.view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 750, height: 500))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Have you tried an Exception Breakpoint?

Comment: I tried an Ex. Breakpoint and posted a minimal rep. example. look please at my answer below.

Comment: Your question is now answered. Please edit the question and remove the answer.

Comment: i edited the question like you advised. looking forward to your help. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSWindow` is released when it is closed. Before ARC this was a usefull feature. It can be switched off by setting the `isReleasedWhenClosed` property to `false`. But then the window stays in memory when it is closed because the `settingsWindow` property is holding on to it. Implement delegate method `windowWillClose` and set `settingsWindow` to `nil` so window is released.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate {

    var settingsWindow: NSWindow!

    // other methods

    @objc func createWindow() {
        settingsWindow = NSWindow(
                    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 750, height: 500),
                    styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled],
                    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        settingsWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        settingsWindow.delegate = self
        settingsWindow.center()
        settingsWindow.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        settingsWindow?.contentViewController = ViewController()
        settingsWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
    
    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        settingsWindow = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Great! That's working. Thanks a lot :)